# Getting Data on Matrix Visual with dynamic column based on slicer selection

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

I have a single table that combines data of all 4 versions of same Project (Project A).

[excel copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hNyrZTNu8O-4Z3jha1AjCyD0tJXzTzpC/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=111637703513802384395&rtpof=true&sd=true)

I need advise on how to add a dynamic column in Matrix Visual so that when two different versions of the Project A is selected from Slicer dropdown visual, the column dates should change according to the selection made in Slicer. For instance if "Project A - Baseline" is selected in one Slicer and "Project A - Update 01" is selected in the next slicer, the dates in matrix visual should change accordingly and DAX formula to calculate the days difference from dynamic dates column as shown in the attachment.

[Matrix Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eX7q.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way:

```
Left Project Start Date = 
VAR ProjectName=MIN('Sheet1'[proj_short_name])
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet1[Plan_Actual_Start_Date],"more then 1 start date")
        ,'Sheet1'[proj_short_name]=ProjectName
    )

Right Project End Date = 
VAR ProjectName=MAX('Sheet1'[proj_short_name])
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet1[Plan_Actual_Finish_Date],"more then 1 end date")
        ,'Sheet1'[proj_short_name]=ProjectName
    )

Matrix header= "Projects Compare " & MIN('Sheet1'[proj_short_name]) & " vs " & MAX('Sheet1'[proj_short_name])
```

[image: one slicer]

Comment: Hi Mik, thanks for helping me out. I tried & it didn't work. I have attached the excel copy in my question & snap is updated for your clarity on my qtn. Thanks.

Comment: @ProjectInsights, please, look at the answer. I don't remeber which value you want to get finally. If you remind me , I'll add it. There are 2 measures of 4, but they are similar.

Comment: And you can't go without task code as you will get multiple start dates for each task name

Comment: thanks mate, I see you got the right result on the visual. I tried the same dax code but ended up getting slightly different result. Can you please share your pbix file with me. admin@projectinsights.com.au, just in case if you wish to send it over email. The final value is going to be a "Start Variance" [working days] for Left & Right Project Start Date & "Finish Variance" [working days] for Left & Right Project End Date. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: I have modified excel copy in question by adding a separate column task_id, task_id is unique to all the tasks in the list. I hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: I sent the file. Regarding Variance. What do you want to get - working days or calendar day? As I understood you want to calculate difference between start days right to left, and difference in duration right to left. It's not clear working days you mean or calendar. And it's will be better to have a formula  like "Start Variance" = right project start date - left project start date...

Comment: Working days as a variance. Sat & Sunday to be excluded from days count. Appreciate it if you can resend the pbix file with variance calculation once done. It's easy to follow that way. Thanks mate. :)

Comment: you are wellcome! Please check the new file and awaiting for your feedback.

Comment: I sent the correction. Let me know if it's ok. In addition to the mail, I wrote in comments --Or like this: ,[Date] IN AntiHolidays. I forgot to add returning value - 1. The correct form will be -  ,[Date] IN AntiHolidays,1

Comment: Mik, please consider *not* collaborating via email. This has set the OP up with unrealistic expectations as to how this platform works - it is not for the purposes of advertising for private or one-to-one advice. Moreover, any help rendered in private no longer benefits the community.